# System Verilog: I am confused about the $stable statement

Tags: system-verilog

I understand that the $stable(expression) statement returns 'True', if the expression being evaluated has the same value as in the previous clock cycle. However, I don't understand why the following is being said in most learning materials:

```
assert property(@(posedge clk) enable == 0 |=> $stable(data));
```

states that data shouldn’t change whilst enable is 0.

As I have proved it, because `|=>` is being used, this will not work for the following example:

```
enable 1110000111

data__ ABCAAAABB

assert ______X___
```

(where A, B and C are some values of the data bus, and X is the point where the assertion would fail)

As you can see, the data has the value `A` while `enable = 0`, so it remains stable. But the assertion would not work as desired, because the data changes from A to B at the same time that enable changes `from 0 to 1`.

So my question is, how would you really implement or code the expression **the data shouldn't change while enable is 0.?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking of

```
assert property(@(posedge clk) (enable == 0)[*2] |-> $stable(data));
```

This means for two consecutive cycles when enable==0, data should not change.

I think "the desired behavior" of the original assertion is not very clear. The state of `enable` is one clock cycle and `$stable` is a condition evaluated over 2 clock cycles. There is a similar argument if overlapping implication `|->`was used. So the question becomes what happens if `(enable==0)` is true for only one clock cycle? How do you want stability of `data` defined?

Comment: IIRC, It is OK for 'enable' to be 0 for just one cycle when applied to a circuit that "holds" data when enable is 0 upon clock transition. For that one cycle the circuit is still expected to keep the data when clock goes from 0 to 1. Therefore it should be OK to use the quoted 'learning materials expression' (valid for a single cycle, except that it just can't be evaluated for the very first cycle where there isn't a 'previous cycle' data to compare to). DISCLAIMER: I'm not versed in verilog - but I know my hardware, when it comes to real-world binary logic circuits.

Comment: Thanks! assert property(@(posedge clk) (enable == 0)[*2] |-> $stable(data)); was what I was looking for!